# #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SHOW DATABASES privilege(s)

Tags: mysql

[image]

I am very very new with mysql thing. Just followed the new boston tutorials on youtube and after I created MySql database and imported the customers database I get the following error when I write SHOW DATABASES

## 1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SHOW DATABASES privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: SHOW DATABASES is a mysql command that queries all databases on a host server.  Since you shouldn't have access to see what other people's DBs are on a shared box this feature is functioning properly.  This post isn't even a question really.  It's more like, "Hey I got an error let me show you what it is."

Comment: he is doing exactly the same thing without an error https://youtu.be/HQQ_hDCUUuI?t=1m9s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is probably because your database is on shared hosting. So, only the database administrator can access the DATABASES SHOW command.

Comment: he is doing exactly the same thing without an error https://youtu.be/HQQ_hDCUUuI?t=1m9s

Comment: Yes, but in the video, we can see mysql is installed on localhost, the user is logged in as root, he has all rights acces on database.